# How to send several rows of google sheet table via email if cell match today's date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

daily I have to send different qty of google sheet table rows (it depends on how many trucks were departed) via e-mail to a few recipients.

Could you help me, please, with an example of how to collect several rows of google table if cell match today's date and then send it via email?

For example, I need to grab all rows with today's date and send data from columns A, B, C, E via e-mail.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Do you have any code that you've been trying to use?

Comment: Welcome. Your question covers a lot of ground. Are you already familiar with scripting? Possibly this Google Tutorial might be helpful [Tutorial: Sending emails from a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) or this topic on [Google Script: getValue from row with today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47058000/1330560).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go step by step. I'm supposing the column A contains the dates. Change it if it's not correct:

1. Declare the variables we will use for this

```
function main() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sheet.getActiveSheet();
  var row_count = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;  
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "dd.MM.yyyy"); //You can use the date format you prefer
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:E"+ (row_count + 1)).getValues(); //We get all the values from A to E and from row 2 to the last one.

  countToday(sheet, today, row_count, data);
  sendEmails(data);


}
```

2. Since we have each row in each position of data, we will compare
   each date with "today", and we will remove (splice) the rows from
   other days. The rows with valid dates will remain in the variable:

```
function countToday(sheet,today, row, data){

  var lastrow = "A" + (row + 1);
  var col_A = sheet.getRange('A2:'+lastrow).getValues();


  for (var i = row; i >= 0; i--){
    if (col_A[i] != today){
      data.splice(i, 1); //
    }

  }

}
```

3. Now that we got each row of elements, we can send the email. We will create an html table so it will be easier to understand. The Mailapp function makes it very simple:

```
function sendEmails(data){

 MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "example1@mail.com" + "example2@mail.com", //You can put as many emails you want
    subject: "Example",
    htmlBody:"<html><body>" + createTable(data)+ "</body></html>"});

}
```

4. To create the html table, we just make a string coded in html with
   the names of the columns from the Sheet. Then we make a table array,
   where we will split each element from `data` separated by coma (that's each sheet cell) and just add it to the end of the variable. < /td> will create the rows for us.

```
function createTable(data){
  var cells = [];

  var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1><tr><th>Date</th><th>Column B</th><th>Column C</th><th>Column D</th><th>Column E</tr></br>";

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      cells = data[i].toString().split(",");
      table = table + "<tr></tr>";

      for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++){
          table = table + "<td>"+ cells[u] +"</td>";
      }
  }

  table=table+"</table></body></html>";
  return table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but before you have to make some changes. I have improved it a little bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example of code. But I can't figure out how to implement preventing function for duplicating emails sending. EMAIL_SENT is working only with the "for" cycle. But in that case, if the cell doesn't contain "EMAIL_SENT" string, the email is sending as many times as there are the empty cells.

```
function main() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("HR-SI B2C");
  var row_count = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;  
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "dd/MM/yyyy"); //You can use the 
  date format you prefer
  var data = sheet.getRange("A3:K"+ (row_count + 1)).getValues(); //We get all the 
  values from A to E and from row 2 to the last one.
  var lastrow = "A" + (row_count + 1);
  var col_A = sheet.getRange('A3:'+lastrow).getDisplayValues();
  var row = data[i];

for (var i = row_count; i >= 0; i--){

  if (col_A[i] != today){
  data.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

if (("K" + (row_count+2)) == "EMAIL_SENT"){

}else if(("D" + (row_count)) == "" || ("F" + (row_count)) == ""){
  dontSendEmail();
}else{
  sendEmailsQHNBRGR(data);

 }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function dontSendEmail(){

 var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "dd/MM/yyyy"); //You can use the 
  date format you prefer

 MailApp.sendEmail({
   to: "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", //You can put as many emails you want
   subject: "Brak wpisanych ilości dla HR i SI za " + today,
   htmlBody:"<html><body> Witam,<br><br>" + 
   "<span><b>Proszę bardzo wpisać ilości dla HR i SI do tabeli</b></span>" +
   "</body></html>"});  

} 

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function sendEmailsQHNBRGR(data, platesNum){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("HR-SI B2C");
  var row_count = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;  
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "dd/MM/yyyy"); //You can use the date format you prefer
  var data = sheet.getRange("A3:G"+ (row_count + 1)).getDisplayValues(); //We get all the values from A to D and from row 2 to the last one.  
  var cells = [];
  var table = "<html><body><table border=3><tr><th>Date</th><th>Day</th><th>HR [pcs]</th><th>HR [ep]</th><th>SI [pcs]</th><th>SI [ep]</th></tr>";
  var lastrow = "A" + (row_count + 1);
  var col_A = sheet.getRange('A3:'+lastrow).getDisplayValues();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "xxxxxxx@gmail.com", //You can put as many emails you want
    subject: "(HR+SI) Orsay prealert " + today,
    htmlBody:"<html><body> Dear All,<br><br>" + 
    "<span style=background-color:rgb(217,234,211)><b>Today we've sent e-com goods in listed quantity:</b></span>" +
    createTable(data) + "<br>" + 
    "<span style=background-color:rgb(255,242,204)><b>@DPD team, could you pick it up 
tomorrow at 02:00 PM?</b></span><br>" + 
    "</body></html>"});  

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 function createTable(data){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("HR-SI B2C");
  var row_count = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;  
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "dd/MM/yyyy"); //You can use the date format you prefer
  var data = sheet.getRange("A3:G"+ (row_count + 1)).getDisplayValues(); //We get all the values from A to D and from row 2 to the last one.  
  var cells = [];
  var table = "<html><body><table border=3><tr><th>Date</th><th>Day</th> 
    <th>Plates number</th><th>HR [pcs]</th><th>HR [ep]</th><th>SI [pcs]</th> 
    <th>SI [ep]</th></tr>";
  var lastrow = "A" + (row_count + 1);
  var col_A = sheet.getRange('A3:'+lastrow).getDisplayValues();

  for (var i = row_count; i >= 0; i--){

    if (col_A[i] != today){
       data.splice(i, 1);
    }

  }

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

      cells = data[i].toString().split(",");
      table = table + "<tr></tr>";

      for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++){
        table = table + "<td>"+ cells[u] +"</td>";
        sheet.getRange("K3:K"+ (row_count + 1)).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");

    }
  }

  table=table+"</table></body></html>";
  return table;

 }
}
```